# googleへのAPKアップロードがバージョン コードエラーを起こす

Tags: android, monaca

今までうまくいっていたgoogleへのAPKアップロードが、急にできなくなりました。いわく「バージョン コード 3 の APK が既に存在するため、別のバージョン コードを使用する必要があります。」。
しかしながら、バージョンコードを設定するAndroidManifest.xmlのバージョンは、android:versionCode="4"となっています。
ほかにバージョンコードを設定するところがありましたか、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

バージョン番号を上げてないんじゃないでしょうか？

設定＞ビルド設定(Androidアプリ設定)＞バージョン

上記のバージョン番号は、必ず一つ前にアップロードしたアプリより上げる必要があります。